# Acumatica - Tab Control - how to show same grid on different tab for different status,

Tags: tabs, acumatica

I am new to Acumatica and have following Queries -
 1. We have multiple tabs for different status and under each tab we show the same grid with the selected tab status.How can i achieve this, Do I need to have multiple Views? Do I need to have multiple Grid control on ASpx?
 2. As the Grid Data is same in all the tabs we need to have common operation for all the tabs, and that operation should be applicable to selected Tab and selected record in that tab, How I can add Action for it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use multiple data views because each one could hold a current object to identify which line of the grid is selected. That pattern can be found in the base product Document/CurrentDocument dataviews:

```
PXSelectJoin<SOShipment,
LeftJoinSingleTable<Customer, On<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<SOShipment.customerID>>,
LeftJoin<INSite, On<INSite.siteID, Equal<SOShipment.siteID>>>>,
Where2<Where<Customer.bAccountID, IsNull,
Or<Match<Customer, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>,
And<Where<INSite.siteID, IsNull,
Or<Match<INSite, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>>>> Document;

PXSelect<SOShipment, Where<SOShipment.shipmentNbr, Equal<Current<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>>> CurrentDocument;
```

For the Actions, you can add them like any other actions: 
[Add button to grid in Acumatica](https://blog.zaletskyy.com/add-button-to-grid-in-acumatica)

I'm not sure whether or not you can map the same action to multiple grid. The easiest way to find out is to try it and if that doesn't work then you can implement multiple actions.